# How to use two secondary keys as a filter? (WHERE f1 AND f2)

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, table

In the contract multi index tables we can filter by the primary key or we can just create an `indexed_by` as an additional index.

Then we have basically two options: filter by the primary key or filter by the additional index.

But what if we want to add a second additional index and `find` for both of them?

Like in a SQL fashion: `index1 = 1 AND index2 = 2`

*I've already asked this question and received the below answer from Dan Larimer, in Official EOS Developers Telegram, but I'm sharing with you because I believe it can help others*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, for this scenario we can create another index that concatenates both indexes and look for it. As an example, let's see a scenario where we can invite accounts to a group and each invitation has an id.

```
// table declaration for invites 
// @abi table invitation i64
struct invitation {
    uint64_t     id;
    uint64_t     group;
    account_name user;

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }

    uint128_t get_user_by_group() const { return combine_ids(group, user); }

    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(invitation, (id)(group)(user))
};
typedef multi_index<N(invitation), invitation, 
  indexed_by<N(user_by_group), const_mem_fun<invitation, uint128_t, 
                              &invitation::get_user_by_group>>
> tb_invitation;

// concatenation of ids example
uint128_t combine_ids(const uint64_t &x, const uint64_t &y) {
    return (uint128_t{x} << 64) | y;
}


// now in your smartcontract, you can look if the user already
// belongs to the specific group
// validates if user is already in the community

tb_invitation invitation(_self, _self);
auto idx_existent_invitation = invitation.template get_index<N(user_by_group)>();
auto group_user_id = combine_ids(group_id, new_user_id);
auto itr_group_user = idx_existent_invitation.find(group_user_id);
eosio_assert(itr_group_user == idx_existent_invitation.end(), 
    "user already invited to group");
```

Besides that, you can also do Dan's suggestion, using two iterators and merging them. This solution works for simple `AND` clauses only. Dan suggestion's would probably be better for `OR` and any other complex filters.

Also, it was my own implementation without Dan eyes, if you can, please suggest any improvements and better approaches on this concatenation! ;)

Comment: `combine_ids` doesn't need a loop. Try `(uint128_t{x} << 64) | y`.

Comment: Thanks @ToddFleming ! I tested and it worked perfectly! EDITED!

Comment: What is group_id & new_user_id?