# Iterating a table by primary key greater than x and secondary key == y

Tags: multi-index, eosio.cdt, primarykey

How does one go about iterating a table for the next largest primary key in a table that also has a specific secondary value?

Values to iterate with:

1. uint64_t last_key_known == 1652645054;
2. name user_value == User B;

Return row #5 only knowing the above.

| row number (just for reference ) | uint64_t Primary Key | name Secondary Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1652644680 | User A |
| 2 | 1652644682 | User A |
| 3 | 1652645054 | User B |
| 4 | 1652645056 | User C |
| 5 | 1652645059 | User B |
| 6 | 1652645060 | User A |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible to query like "where user_value == User B AND Primary Key >= 1652645054 You have a few options:

1. Use scopes: define your table with user (name) as scope and save each user's records in his scope. this way you will have only 1 primary index. I'm not sure this is relevant for you use case...
2. query by one of the indexes and iterate over the results. for example, get all records for user B (by the secondary index), and iterate to get the records with primary >= 1652645054. This solution can work only if you don't have many records per each user, as you might hit the cpu limit.
3. Implement something like in this [answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/32/6628)

Hope this helps